# 'Models.LoginViewModel' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My code is:

```
@sample.Models.LoginViewModel
@{
    string user = Session["users"].ToString();
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";  
}
```

I get the error:

> '@sample.Models.LoginViewModel' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Please give any idea to resolve my issue.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here ? That syntax is not clear. Specify more details.

Comment: try @model sample.Models.LoginViewModel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change code

```
@sample.Models.LoginViewModel
```

as

```
@model sample.Models.LoginViewModel
```

ie is

```
@model sample.Models.LoginViewModel

    @{
       if(Session["users"] != null)
       {
        string user = Session["users"].ToString();
       } 
    }
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";  
    }
```

@model keyword should be at the beginning u r just specifying only the model name

Comment: if i am using @model , i resolved above issue but i am facing another one issue

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  @model MvcApplication127.Models.LoginViewModel
Line 2:  @{
Line 3:      string user = Session["users"].ToString();
Line 4:  }
Line 5:  @{

Comment: check `@{ if(Session["users"] !=null) { string user = Session["users"].ToString();}` try this

Answer (score 3):

you are doing wrong

```
@sample.Models.LoginViewModel
```

insted of use

```
@model sample.Models.LoginViewModel
```

Answer (score 1):

You syntax is wrong, change

`@sample.Models.LoginViewModel` to `@model sample.Models.LoginViewModel`